# Disable touching events on background Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a map fragment which's view is available when user logs in. When user is logged off alert showing logging form pops out while map is still visible in the background. My problem is that map and menu still reacts to touch events even when login dialog is on the top, how can I prevent this from happening?

Map fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends MapFragment{

    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        ...

        m_loginManager = new LoginManager(getActivity());
        m_loginManager.show();

        ...

        return v;
    }
```

Login Dialog:

```
public class LoginManager extends Dialog {

    public LoginManager(Activity activity)
    {
        super(activity);
        setContentView(R.layout.alert_login);
       ...
    }   
}
```

alert_login.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="15dp"
          android:clickable="true">


          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/username"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/userName"
              android:layout_width="300dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:ems="10"
              android:inputType="text"
              android:text="" />

          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/password"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/password"
              android:layout_width="300dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:ems="10"
              android:inputType="textPassword"
              android:text="" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/loginButton"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/loginButton" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

Here how it looks:
[image]

Comment: by "... menu still reacts..." do you mean to the menu button?

Comment: let me edit my question

Answer (score 0):

**Disableing the menu button**
In orrder to disable the menu button you can override `onPrepareOptionsMenu`.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    return false;
}
```

In order to disable touch events in `MainFragment` while `alert_login.xml` appears you should set the `clickable` property to be true.

alert_login.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:background="@android:color/white"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:padding="15dp"
      android:clickable="true">

      //...
```

Comment: Regarding the disabled menu: it can't be dynamically enabled after overriding onPrepareOptionsMenu, right?